# I am getting error in laravel query language

Tags: php, laravel-5

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Connection::table()

I am passing the argument here in the table function. I am getting this error on every function of the database which I am using.

It is working fine when I create the object of the model and then use the function `table()`.

This is the code which I am using.

```
return DB::table('crop_growth')
         ->leftJoin('farmer_details', 'crop_growth.farmer_id', '=', 'farmer_details.id')
         ->select('crop_growth.id', 'crop_growth.remind_after', 'crop_growth.reason', 'crop_growth.is_read', 'farmer_details.name', 'farmer_details.phone')
         ->where('crop_growth.emp_id', $empId)
         ->where('crop_growth.remind_after', '!=', null)
         ->orderBy('crop_growth.is_read', 'ASC')
         ->orderBy('crop_growth.remind_after', 'ASC')
         ->get();
```

Comment: The error described does not match this code-snippet.

Comment: This code is just fine, are you sure you're getting an error on this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the table method in your query then you are set.

```
DB::connection('mysql / <or whatever mane you called it>')->table('crop_growth')-> rest of your query.
```

if you still have the error you can set the database in your table field.

```
table('<database>.crop_growth')
```

although i will set a test select first then the left join then the actual select but this is OK to.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you it is working for me, but do I need to do that at every place where I am using like DB:: table('crop_growth')

Comment: Well it depends on your database configuration (miss configuration maybe ?). if have changed your connection or if you are using a remote database connection or a radios connection then yes you need to call the database first then the table. Good luck